# SQL Server Always Encrypted on AWS RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Does anyone know if RDS for SQL Server supports Always Encrypted? If it does has anyone every used AWS KMS as the Certificate Store?

Answer (score 0):

RDS for SQL Server supports Always Encrypted.
It is mentioned in the documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html

AWS KMS can't be used for the Certificate store.
The options are:

- Azure Key Vault
- Windows Certificate Store on a client machine
- Hardware security module

RDS also supports Always Encrypted with Secure Enclaves, but with some limitations in regards to the setup:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/modernizing-with-aws/sql-server-always-encrypted-with-secure-enclaves/

Comment: Pretty sure you can't use enclaves on RDS. The above link is relating to using enclaves when running SQL Server on an EC2.